# Error with importing interfaces in typescript

Tags: typescript, import, importerror

I'm having an issue with importing interfaces in Typescript (2.1.4).

This is my interface

```
// src/cache.model.ts
import * as ng from 'angular';

module angularjsIndexedDB {

    export interface Cache {
        get<T>(key : string): ng.IPromise<T>;
        getOrCreate<T>(key : string, fetcher: () => ng.IPromise<T>): ng.IPromise<T>;
        put<T>(key : string, value: T): ng.IPromise<void>;
        updateChecksum(serverModelChecksum: number): ng.IPromise<void>;
    }

}
```

And this is the class in the same module that implements the interface.

```
// src/indexeddb-store.service.ts
module angularjsIndexedDB {

    export class IndexedDBStore implements Cache {
        // (... code implementing the interface ...)
    }

}
```

Even though the interface is in the same TS module I get the error `TS2304:Cannot find name 'Cache'.`

If I change the implementation to have a direct reference

```
// src/indexeddb-store.service.ts
module angularjsIndexedDB {

    export class IndexedDBStore implements angularjsIndexedDB.Cache {
        // (... code implementing the interface ...)
    }

}
```

the error becomes `TS2694:Namespace 'angularjsIndexedDB' has no exported member 'Cache'.` Even though the interface is clearly exported.

I've tried other things like adding

```
import { Cache } from "./cache.model";
```

or

```
import { angularjsIndexedDB.Cache } from "./cache.model";
```

but these come up empty too.

What's weird is that I didn't have an issue using this code before. Is there something I've overlooked?

**EDIT:**

This is my `tsconfig.json`. I did a few more tests and I believe there is a different issue that causes the wrong error to show up. I will reconstruct the components to try and identify the issue.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outFile": "release/index.js"
  }
}
```

**EDIT2:**
I found the 'cause' of this issue. The `cache.model.ts` file uses the `import * as ng from 'angular';` statement on the first line. I've added this line initially since TS could not resolve the `ng.` objects in my files. There must be a bug in the error reporting that causes this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the same error you are.  Here is my code:

cache.model.ts:

```
module angularjsIndexedDB {

    export interface Cache {
    }

}
```

indexeddb-store.service.ts:

```
module angularjsIndexedDB {

    export class IndexedDBStore implements Cache {
        // (... code implementing the interface ...)
    }

}
```

And I compile like this:

tsc

Using tsc v2.1.4 and there are no errors.

Here are possibilities:

1. Some compiler options are causing this.
2. You are somehow not compiling the `cache.model.ts` file.
3. The code you are showing me is incomplete.

Can you try my setup above and see if it works for you?

Comment: I've pinpointed the issue to be related to my import statement. By introducing it the TS error reporting gave a number of irrelevant issues. I've removed the import statement but I am confused as to how I am supposed to do imports now.